# How to call JSF action from WDCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

How to call a JSF action in WDcalender, i am using WDCALENDAR in JSF RichFaces, To load Edit page need to call an action, below is my code.

I need to replace Edit.jsp with JSF action.

```
 function Edit(data) {//Edit Link 
                var eurl = 'Edit.jsp?id={0}&amp;start={2}&amp;end={3}&amp;isallday={4}&amp;title={1}';
                if (data) {
                    var url = StrFormat(eurl, data);
                    OpenModelWindow(url, { width: 735, height: 500, caption: "Manage  The Calendar", onclose: function() {
                        $("#gridcontainer").reload();
                    }
                    });
                }
            }
```

in above code, contents of Edit.jsp will be displayed in a Pop window...

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method in `managed-bean` by using a `<a4j:jsFunction>` component.

**Javascript:**

```
function Edit(data) {
   callBeanMethod();
   ............
}
```

**XHTML:**

```
<h:form id="test">
    <a4j:jsFunction name="callBeanMethod" action="#{myBean.myAction()}">
</h:form>
```